# Does it make logical sense to "not hold by OU kashrus"?

Tags: food, kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification, organizations

Apparently there are some people who do not rely on the OU for kashrus.  I have seen a few online references (i.e. [this Matzav post](http://matzav.com/the-matzav-rant-the-i-dont-eat-ou-fallacy)) that claim this makes no logical sense, since virtually every other hechsher relies on the OU for ingredients.  Is this true?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: It depends on what. I wouldn't expect someone who holds of Chodosh or Chalav Yisrael to eat OU bagel and cream cheese.

Comment: I think it makes perfectly logical sense as long as the person who espouses this position is consistent and takes it upon himself to investigate and insure that each ingredient is either supervised by an agency he respects in a way which he can live with, or that he checks each ingredient himself. Why wouldn't it be logical? Maybe you mean "feasible"

Comment: @DoubleAA but in genaral not just their milk, cholov yisrael holders will eat other OU foods that dont require milk

Comment: @MosheY And chodosh holders will eat OU foods that don't have grain. I chose bagel and cream cheese for a reason.

Comment: @Dan, no I mean *logical*... if they hold of Star-K but not OU, but when they are using a Star-K product it contains OU ingredients, then they are not really avoiding OU, are they?

Comment: @DesertStar but if they hold Star K then they are holding Star K. If Star-K has standards which mimic OU and they have investigated the ingredients to know that those standards are met then there aren't really relying on the OU. If they trust without investigating then they shouldn't be relied on because that would make the choice to avoid the OU logically consistent. It may not be feasible, though, to expect the star-k to investigate reduntantly, so while it could logically be possible to avoid the OU it may be practically impossible if one relies on any popular hashgocha.

Answer (score 6):

It's not true that the claim makes no logical sense. Although most or all other kashrut orgs rely on the OU to some extent, they do so to varying levels: Some will rely on it totally, others will rely on it only for uncomplicated ingredients, or only in cases where there is no possibility of conflicting standards. I believe the OU itself has an internal policy concerning which orgs are fully trusted and which are relied upon only in limited cases.

Comment: Moreover it makes no logical sense because you can eat only your own grown vegetables.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the answer to your question but I do know that in order to answer this question you must know all of the kashrus related responsibilities the OU fulfills and which of them are taken over by the other hechsher. 
The ingredients of an item is not the only criterion required to make something kosher.
I think that this question might be assuming an oversimplified view of the enormous system required to ensure that something comes out kosher from start to finish.

Just to make it clear, I am embarrassingly under-educated in this arena and would love to hear people's input. I am just cautions of people seeing one piece of the entire system, taking it out of context and judging it based on a position that is both ignorant of the halachos and the system that any given agency has in place.