# slander or truth abou OU Kashrus

Tags: hechsher-certification, lashon-hara-slander

I don't want to look like a total jerk but i heard from someone whose sister is married to an important rav that the OU kashrus is not so reliable as you might believe. they depend on paperwork that could be phoney and don't really inspect on the spot or don't go there enough and maybe some of them even are themselves not as conscientious honest as they should be. does anyone know anything?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18274/1569, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/143/1569

Comment: Also, [this](http://www.israel613.com/books/KASHRUT_ENCYCLOPEDIA3-E.pdf#page=13) quotes the author of the Be'er Mosheh as saying, "As far as relying on the hashgachah of the OU, G-d forbid that we should do so..." I have not seen any other source apart from that approbation that quotes him as saying that, however

Comment: @ba Which page of the pdf please?

Comment: I'm willing to put in the 4th close vote for Not Constructive.

Comment: @DoubleAA I put `#page=13` at the end of the link to get it to that page automatically

Comment: yerachmiel - this 'important rav' wouldn't happen to be involved with a competing kashrus agency, would he? Just asking...

Comment: See the tshuva in Siach Nachum (R. Nachum Rabinowitz) on the reliability of the OU.

Answer (score 2):

The OU is a very reliable Hashgacha on which ALL Hashgachos rely. If you eat anything processed in any way then you are eating food that is certified by the OU. They have many big Gedolim who are in charge including Rabbi Belsky, Rabby Genack, Rabbi Schachter and they are absolutely reliable. They may have standards which some people disagree with (Cholov Stam for example) however they are 100% reliable, they do not hide their standards, and do not play any games.

Comment: Rav Belsky has stated himself in public that his hechsher is from the best in the world and they adhere to the highest standards in everything without cutting corners. He said this in a shiur once explaning the position of OU and Chalav Stam (which they give a hechsher on such products.)

Comment: Do you have a source that ALL hashgachos rely on the OU?

Comment: @DoubleAA - Some Hashgachos would like you to believe that they are better, and that they do things differently. However speak to any Mashgiach candidly and they will all tell you that all Hashgachos rely on the OU. Yes there are those that will not rely on Dairy products as they only give Hashgacha on Chalav Yisrael and there are those that may not rely on some other items, however they all rely on the OU to some extent, and many completely.

Comment: @GershonGold So....no.

Comment: @DoubleAA - So ......yes. My source is from Mashgichim I have spoken to, such as Rabbi Juravel, Rabbi Eisen and others. Hey gulp! I put names, not like the questioner who is hiding the name of his Motzi Shem Ra.